# GitLab: How to use !reference tag in the presence of yaml-checkers

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, ruamel.yaml

I want to use the `!reference` tag in the GitLab pipeline definition.

At the same time I have yaml-checkers like `check-yaml` in the `pre-commit` tool (https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html). As an example, this checker uses `ruamel.yaml` python package to load a yaml file. The package then complains along the lines of *"could not determine a constructor for the tag"*.

Is there away to include the definition of the tag in my pipeline to satisfy the checker? Otherwise this makes the usage of `!reference` tag impossible in several of my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!reference` is a custom [YAML tag](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#tags) used in configuration files for GitLab ([`!reference` tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags)) and probably other services. Same error can happen with other custom tags like [`!Ref`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) for AWS `serverless.yml`.

I think there are 3 possible solutions.

**Option 1**: If you have other YAML files (e.g. `gitlab-ci.yml`), one way to overcome this is to exclude the non-standard file (e.g. `serverless.yml`) from checks.

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml
        exclude: serverless.yml
```

**Option 2**: Or as stated by [anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520533/648044) you can run only unsafe checks (*but this will disable more advanced checks for other YAML files*):

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml
        args: [--unsafe]
```

**Option 3**: If you, as me, have other YAML files and you want to check them strictly, the best option is to exclude `serverless.yml` from complete checks and check that file with the [`--unsafe`](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks#check-yaml) option.

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    hooks:
    # basic checks for custom yaml syntax
    -   id: check-yaml
        name: Check YAML (unsafe)
        args: [--unsafe]
        files: serverless.yml
    # check other yaml files normally
    -   id: check-yaml
        exclude: serverless.yml
```

---

**Note**: I'll copy here the error message I got before finding the solution myself because I couldn't find this page when I was checking an AWS `serverless.yml` file.

**`could not determine a constructor for the tag '!Ref'`**

Comment: `!reference` is a tag. Tags are standard YAML. Tagging is used extensively in the YAML specification e.g. for explicit typing. Some parsers cannot handle tags, either the ones they don't know about or because they are incomplete parsers, but that does not cause a valid construct to be non-standard YAML.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks, I've fixed the misleading statement.

Answer (score 1):

`!reference` is a nonstandard extension as such you will need to use the [--unsafe](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks#check-yaml) option

```yaml
    -   id: check-yaml
        args: [--unsafe]
```

Comment: The `--unsafe` option only parser the YAML document and so doesn't find errors that ruamel.yaml only detects in the later (composer, constructor) phases. E.g. duplicate keys in a mapping will not be detected.

Comment: indeed, that is exactly the point of `--unsafe` -- it turns off all the portability and correctness checks

Comment: from my beginner point of view the point of Anthon seems to be valid and maybe `--unsafe` is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I can't determine how `ruamel.yaml` is used in gitlab, but if you can control
how the `ruamel.yaml.YAML()` instance is created, you should make sure it
uses the default `typ` (by not specifying it), or the equivalent (`typ='rt').
This will allow any valid tag to be loaded (and dumped) without
the need to specify a constructor. The tag can be used on both collection
types (mapping, sequence), as well as most scalars.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- !reference {a: 1, b: 2}
- !reference [1, 2, 3]
- !reference "abc"
- !reference 3.14
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- !reference {a: 1, b: 2}
- !reference [1, 2, 3]
- !reference "abc"
- !reference 3.14
```

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do about it (I'm using pre-commit tool and there is not much flexibility in how the user can configure its usage of `ruamel`), but the suggestion sounds good.

Comment: Switching to the `type='rt'` seems to be too tricky as it would require a change to the pre-commit hook code, while it uses `type='safe'` at the moment, see [here](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/blob/df25ab1ba8b2d70333ec8f447ad66cef519a654f/pre_commit_hooks/check_yaml.py#L10).

Comment: Why would that be tricky? If you are concerned about safity: the roundtrip parser is as safe as the 'safe' parser as it also doesn't instantiate arbitrary classes, it just creates a dict/list subclass on which the tag (and comments) be attached as an attribute.

Comment: I posted an [issue](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/issues/708), to at least allow `typ='rt'` using a command line option

Comment: @MischaLisovyi I can't recommend using the `--unsafe` option. It only uses the YAML parser phase and that doesn't detect errors like e.g. duplicate keys which are checked in later stages of loading